# My keras model seems toskip the last epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine-tune a bert model with Keras. I set the epoch number to 2 however it seems that it skips the last epoch. I don't have any early-stopping setting in the model.  Here is my code:

```
epochs = 2
batch_size = 24
init_lr = 2e-5
print(f'Fine tuning {tfhub_handle_encoder} model')
steps_per_epoch = train_df.shape[0] // batch_size
num_train_steps = steps_per_epoch * epochs
num_warmup_steps = num_train_steps // 10
validation_steps = val_df.shape[0] // batch_size
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((train_df['query'].values,train_df['doc'].values),np.array(train_labels)))
train_set = train_set.batch(24)
train_set = train_set.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)


preprocess_inputs = preprocessor.inputs   // The input of Bert Preprocessor  
bert_input_data = preprocessor(preprocess_inputs)  // The output of the preprocessor 
bert_output = bert(bert_input_data)  // feed the outputs from the preprocessors to BERT 
encoder_output = encoder(bert_output) // get the bert output 
reconstruction =decoder(encoder_output) // pass the bert output to a decoder 
bert_qe_vae = tf.keras.Model(preprocess_inputs,[encoder_output,reconstruction])
all_losses={'encoder_output':kl_divergence,'reconstruction':recon_loss}
optimizer = optimization.create_optimizer(
  init_lr=init_lr,
  num_train_steps=num_train_steps,
  num_warmup_steps=num_warmup_steps,
  optimizer_type='adamw')
bert_qe_vae.compile(optimizer=optimizer,loss=all_losses)
bert_qe_vae.fit(x=train_set,
        epochs=epochs,
        steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)
```

Here is the log of the training process:

Fine tuning https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/bert_en_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12/3 model

```
Epoch 1/2
12816/12816 [==============================] - 8380s 652ms/step - loss: 647.3066 - encoder_loss: 83.6949 - decoder_loss: 563.6116 
Epoch 2/2
12816/12816 [==============================] - 0s 2us/step - loss: 549.6426 - encoder_loss: 19.1478 - decoder_loss: 530.4949
```

It seems that the model just skips the second (the last) epoch as it takes 0s to finish the epoch. Are there any mistakes with my optimizer setting?

Comment: What happens if you run the model for 3 epochs? Does it run `n-1` epochs or just 1 epoch?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I haven't tried 3 epochs yet. I will try that later